# Policy Privacy Italian / EU and anonymous blog

Tags: privacy

I would like to write a personal blog without making my real identity public.
It's not a "war blog" or similar, I would like to write about several personal problems and give (if possible) some comfort to other people in my same situation.

In Italy (and I think in all EU) if you collect emails for the comments and/or you use Google Analytics, you need to write a Policy Privacy (see Iubenda, for example), with your name, surname, and home address.

I want my blog perfectly anonymous (for visitors, not important for the Justice... or "The Big Brother"). Nothing of illegal. Simply: if a friend of mine search on Google and discover my blog, I don't want him to think that I'm the author.

I did register a .com domain with an Italian provider, that re-registered the .com with a UK company. I used the hidden shield, so my data with a public whois are hidden.

I'm using hostinger, free php hosting with server in Ukraine and business in UK.

Am I free at the moment to write down the privacy with my real data? Ukraine will be in EU from 2016, I did read on Google.

I'll write a policy privacy. I'll tell you to use a free - temp email. I don't want send any newsletter or resend. No no. I want only a pacific discuss on several problems.

Someone give me the hint to host in Russia. But I don't understand the Russian language. And their site (of free php hosting!) are all written in Russian language.

So, if you are in my same situation, what your suggestion / what you would do to protect your anonymity?

A hosting in USA? And where exactly? Free php hosting.. please ;)

Comment: When you say 'UK' do you mean Ukraine or United Kingdom ?

Comment: "If you collect emails or use Google Analytics, you need to write a privacy policy".  The conclusion is obvious: don't collect emails or use Google Analytics.  And consult a lawyer if you need legal advice.

Comment: I think all this privacy policy requirements are more guidelines than actual laws; ie. it will only apply if someone actually complains. Given that you do nothing illegal there is no reasons for people to complain. About the hosting though, don't rely on free hosting. I suggest you look into ready to use blogging platforms like Wordpress (on which you can sign up using fake data and possibly use Tor if you really need to hide, from the government for example) but as far as "raw" PHP hosting goes, you'll have to pay if you want decent service.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but I think you could use a blogging service like Blogger.com. In that case the provider would be responsible for providing their identity information and protecting the privacy of your visitors.